# Firebase child_changed for tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using `child_added` to populate a table, I use `append()` to show the data on the HTML table, but how do I do it with `child_changed`? Should I delete the row and then append a new one with the changed information? If so, how do I delete this row? Or maybe use something else instead of `append()` to update the data on the HTML table?

**HTML Table**

```
<table id="tableAssets" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">

    <thead>
      <tr id="tableHeader">
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Brand</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="table_body"> </tbody>

</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

  var assetKey = snap.child("id").val();
  var name = snap.child("name").val();
  var brand = snap.child("brand").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr data-id='"+assetKey+"'>"+
                          "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + name + "</td>" +
                          "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + brand + "</td>" +

                          "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'><div buttons>"+
                                  "<button class='delete-btn'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button>"+" "+
                                  "</div></td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For child added use id in tr

```
 rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

      var assetKey = snap.child("id").val();
      var name = snap.child("name").val();
      var brand = snap.child("brand").val();

      $("#table_body").append("<tr id='row"+assetKey+"'>"+
                              "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + name + "</td>" +
                              "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + brand + "</td>" +

                              "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'><div buttons>"+
                                      "<button class='delete-btn'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button>"+" "+
                                      "</div></td></tr>");
    });
```

For Child Changed

```
rootRef.on("child_changed", snap => {

      var assetKey = snap.child("id").val();
      var name = snap.child("name").val();
      var brand = snap.child("brand").val();
      editrow = "row"+assetKey;

      document.getElementById("editrow").innerHTML = "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + name + "</td>" +
                              "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + brand + "</td>" +

                              "<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'><div buttons>"+
                                      "<button class='delete-btn'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button>"+" "+
                                      "</div></td>");
    });
```

This will help.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I have found an issue when I change the `data-id` to `id`, bcause i'm currently using the `data-id` on a delete button, and when I change it to `id`, it stops working...

the delete button code is as follows:
https://pastebin.com/YGvK1mhT